# Merge historical table records asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm developing an asp.net core mvc project, I have 2 tables MyData and MyDataHistorical. These tables generates from 2 different table model classes which have same columns, only difference names, MyDataHistorical stores data which before a spesific time.

For example when I want to send data to my view page from one of these tables, I'm using linq queries and set data to a list of table model type.

But I want to bind data from a date range, which contains records from both tables. I couldn't find a way for merge 2 list which have different types.

I'm sending my list which has my table model type to the view as json data for bind to datatable. But I want to send that 'result' data contains data from MyData and MyDataHistorical records for selected date range. For example a list of records from last month to the present, some data is in historical table and others in MyData table.

```
List<MyData> theList = new List<MyData>();
var list=GetData<MyData>(x=>x.date==myDate);
theList=list;

List<MyDataHistorical> theListHistorical = new List<MyDataHistorical>();
var listHistorical=GetData<MyDataHistorical>(x=>x.date==myDate);
theListHistorical=listHistorical;


 list = list.Select(x => new MyData
            {
                Id= x.Id,
                Name= x.Name,
                DepartmentId=x.DepartmentId
            }).ToList();

 var result = from s in list select s;

 dataTable.data = result.ToArray();

 return Json(dataTable, new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings());
```

Table model classes:

```
public class MyData
{
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
}

public class MyDataHistorical
{
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public int DepartmentId { get; set; }

}
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: you can create another class (viewmodel), which has the exact params as those classes and after getting data from database you can set those data in a viewmodel by a loop, if i understood right the problem. Please tell me, exactly what you want as output?

Comment: thank you so much for your answer, I edited my question and tried explain what I want as output.

Comment: please can you add to your question "MyData" and  "MyDataHistorical" classes?

Comment: I edited my question for model classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you filter by date, at least you should have date property in both classes.
After that, you can do :

```
List<MyData> theList = new List<MyData>();
var list=GetData<MyData>(x=>x.date==myDate);
theList=list;

List<MyDataHistorical> theListHistorical = new List<MyDataHistorical>();
var listHistorical=GetData<MyDataHistorical>(x=>x.date==myDate);
theListHistorical=listHistorical;


list.AddRange(listHistorical.Select(x => new MyData()
        {
            Id= x.Id,
            Name= x.Name,
            DepartmentId=x.DepartmentId
        }));

dataTable.data = list.ToArray();

return Json(dataTable, new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings());
```

Comment: That solved my problem, I didn't know I can add range from different type like this, thank you so much!